# How to sync between local git repos?

Tags: git

I have `repoA` repo, then I created `repo` repo with branch `branchA`, I want branch `branchA` synced with `repoA`, How can I do that?

Comment: Is `repo` a clone of `repoA`, or a completely different repository?

Comment: It would be easiest if you could post a minimal reproducible example which illustrates your problem, starting perhaps with `git init repoA; git init repo` and some commands/actions to populate these repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
git remote add repoA /path/to/repoA
git branch --set-upstream branchA repoA/master
```